How to get integer value from TextField with textformatter
I have JavaFX custom dialog that has TextFields with TextFormatters using IntegerStringConverters. I'm successfully limiting the input to digits, so the content of the TextField is definitely an integer (ok, it might be out of range - I'll cross that bridge next).
My problem is how to get the values in and out of the TextFields as integers. All the methods and members I can find still expect or return Strings. Is the TextFormatter just for binding, or is there some way I can read and write the value as integers?
Here's the controller for the custom dialog (I've not bothered to show the numberValidationFormatter because it's pretty standard):
package org.eu.tr480_free.stitcher

import javafx.fxml.FXML
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader
import javafx.scene.control.*
import javafx.stage.Modality
import javafx.stage.Window
import javafx.util.converter.IntegerStringConverter
import org.eu.tr480_free.stitcher.View.numberValidationFormatter
import java.io.IOException

class NewFileDlg(val window: Window) : Dialog<ButtonType>() {

    @FXML
    lateinit var FabricCombo: ComboBox<FabricType>

    @FXML
    lateinit var rows: TextField

    @FXML
    lateinit var columns: TextField

    init {
        try {
            val loader = FXMLLoader()
            loader.location = javaClass.getResource("new_file_dialog.fxml")
            loader.setController(this)

            initOwner(window)
            initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL)
            isResizable = false
            title = "New File"
            dialogPane = loader.load()
            rows.textFormatter = TextFormatter(IntegerStringConverter(), 0, numberValidationFormatter())
            columns.textFormatter= TextFormatter(IntegerStringConverter(), 0, numberValidationFormatter())
        }
        catch (e: IOException) {
            throw RuntimeException("Unable to load asset: new file dialog")
        }
        for (f in FabricType.values()) {
            FabricCombo.items.add(f)
        }
    }
}

Edit:
This seems to be specifically about Kotlin's interface with JavaFX. If I explicitly set the generic type of TextFormatter to be TextFormatter<Int>, Kotlin warns me that the <Int> is redundant because Kotlin does type inference, but with or without the generic specification it decides the type of the return from (the equivalent of) getTextFormatter().getValue() is Any! - essentially, a (potentially) nullable Object.
Because this is a custom dialog, it won't be hanging around, so setting watchers doesn't seem a sensible way to go. So perhaps I do have to resort to manual casting (and handling the fact that Kotlin doesn't know whether the call to getValue() might return a null, but I don't mind that).
Further edit: The response I have marked as the answer (because it gave me the clue I needed) was Java specific. Because this is a Kotlin question, here's how the solution translates to Kotlin.
In the controller for my dialog shown above, I add:
    val rowsTextFormatter = TextFormatter<Int>(IntegerStringConverter(), 0, numberValidationFormatter())
    val colsTextFormatter = TextFormatter<Int>(IntegerStringConverter(), 0, numberValidationFormatter())

and change
  rows.textFormatter = TextFormatter(IntegerStringConverter(), 0, numberValidationFormatter())
  columns.textFormatter= TextFormatter(IntegerStringConverter(), 0, numberValidationFormatter())

to
   rows.textFormatter = rowsTextFormatter
   columns.textFormatter= colsTextFormatter

Then I can get the values of text fields via the formatters instead of via the TextFields:
    val dialog = NewFileDlg(stage)
    val result = dialog.showAndWait()
    if (result.isPresent && result.get().buttonData == ButtonBar.ButtonData.OK_DONE) {
        val rows = dialog.rowsTextFormatter.value
        val cols = dialog.colsTextFormatter.value
        // ...
    }

And Kotlin knows they're integers, no casting or null handling necessary.

Can you  use Integer#parseInt(String s) instead of a converter?

"I've not bothered to show the numberValidationFormatter because it's pretty standard" -> please provide the code to create a [mcve].  It makes it more likely you will get useful answers.

Don't the obvious method calls (https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html#getValue() and https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html#setValue(V)) work?

The obvious method calls return Kotlin type Any - roughly, "Object" - and I still need to parse it to an Int. Which, of course, I can do. It just seems smelly when there's a converter already in play.

"The obvious method calls return Kotlin type Any" -> I don't know Kotlin, but in Java, the TextFormatter is typed generic, where the type represents the return type.  If you don't specify the type of the formatter, then the value won't have a type either.  e.g. with TextFormatter formatter = new TextFormatter(); then formatter.getValue() will just return an Object.  But, with TextFormatter<Integer> formatter = new TextFormatter<>(); then formatter.getValue() will return an Integer.

Can you write this in Kotlin to get the value as an Int instead of an Any?  getTextFormatter().getValue<Int>().  It would seem possible from my reading of Kotlin Generic functions, but I don't write Kotlin, so I didn't try it and may have misunderstood.  Not sure why it cannot infer the type like Java does, but, oh well.

When you say "perhaps I do have to resort to manual casting", I guess you do use something like the "Safe" (nullable) cast operator and write getTextFormatter().getValue() as? Int.

I think, if you have a kotlin specific solution, even if it isn't ideal for you, then you should write an answer which details your solution and reasoning, as it is a kotlin question after all and not a Java one, so a kotlin answer would seem worthwhile to me.

You get the value out of the text formatter by asking for it.
I'll provide the answer in Java as I don't write Kotlin.
TextFormatter is generically typed to the type it is formatting, in this case an Integer.
You get the value from the formatter by calling getValue on the formatter.  That will return the value in the specific type specified for the formatter.
To do that you have to have a reference to the formatter that you can call getValue on.  You can either store the reference (like I do in the code below), or you can ask the text field for its formatter when it is needed.
The value in the formatter is a property, so you can bind to it or listen to changes on it.  You can also set it to indirectly change the text in the text field to match a set value.
For the example below, I don't limit the user input to valid integers when they are typing because that it irrelevant to getting the value from the formatter.

To use the example, run the app, enter an integer value in the text field, and press the enter key to confirm the value.  A change listener will listen for the changes to the value in the textformatter, get the changed value from the text formatter, convert the integer value to a String and then set the text for the label to the converted String.
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.converter.IntegerStringConverter;

public class TextFormatterApp extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Label fieldValue = new Label();

        TextField formattedField = new TextField();
        TextFormatter<Integer> integerTextFormatter = new TextFormatter<>(
                new IntegerStringConverter()
        );
        formattedField.setTextFormatter(
                integerTextFormatter
        );

        integerTextFormatter.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            fieldValue.setText(
                    Integer.toString(
                            integerTextFormatter.getValue()
                    )
            );
        });

        VBox layout = new VBox(10, formattedField, fieldValue);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }
}


Writing in Java is fine for me, as I'm doing this as an exercise in learning Kotlin, so I'm doing a lot of getting it working in Java then translating to Kotlin..
My problem is, you've accessed the value by adding a listener, which is exactly what I said was irrelevant in my case, This is the result from a custom dialog which is about to go out of scope. so the listener will be listening to a null reference. I don't want a listener, I want the value.

@digitig If you want a specific solution for your use case you must provide the requested [mcve] (preferably in Java if you want more answers).

In your question, you never wrote that accessing the value through a listener is irrelevant.

You can get the value from the formatter without a listener as noted in the answer, and other comments, by calling getValue() on the formatter (e.g. textField.getTextFormatter().getValue()) but you must call it at a time when the value is there (the user has committed the change to the text field). For a dialog, that will probably be after showAndWait is called. If you throw away the formatter or textField reference, you can't get the value -> you need a reference to access stuff.

Dialogs in JavaFX are a bit tricky to use and have a very specific API and default look.  Getting a typed return value from a dialog is a different question than getting the value of text formatter. Dialogs are typed, and can return a result, rather than Dialog<ButtonType>, you can have Dialog<YourType> and you can call getResult on the dialog to get the result.  Or you can add a method of your own.  e.g. CustomDialog myDialog = new CustomDialog();  customDialog.showAndWait(); customDialog.getFormattedValue(); where getFormattedValue() returns textField.getTextFormatter().getValue().

I've marked that as the answer, because it gave me the idea I needed to solve it. "[Y]ou can ask the text field for its formatter when it is needed" doesn't work because Kotlin doesn't know the generic type of the text formatter when you ask for it, so it treats it as TextFormatter<Any>. But if I store the reference, as you suggested, then Kotlin does know the generic type of that and knows that the value method returns an int. Four lines of type checking, null checking and error logging reduces to the simple assignment I wanted all along.
